# Return Value from input id element using selenium and beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I’m using selenium and beautiful soup with python 3.6.  I have page source like the example below.  I’m trying to locate the element maybe using the input id and then I want to return the value “5”.  I’ve tried the code below but it isn’t working, can anyone suggest how to  do this?  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('UserMaximumFileCount’).Value()

# tstsoup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

# tstsoup.find_all('value',{'id':'UserMaximumFileCount'})

# driver.findElement(By.id("input_name")).getAttribute("value")
```

source:

```
<input id="UserMaximumFileCount" name="UserMaximumFileCount" type="hidden" value="5">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to get the value using selenium

```
driver.find_element_by_id('UserMaximumFileCount’).get_attribute('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Get_attribute value

```
driver.find_element_by_id("UserMaximumFileCount").get_attribute('value')
```

Or You can use JavaScripts Executor.

```
element=driver.find_element_by_name("UserMaximumFileCount")
print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].value;", element))
```